# Segundo e Terceiro menor elementos em C

Tags: c, array

O programa pede para imprimir o segundo e o terceiro menor elemento de um vetor. Iniciei com a lógica do menor valor para imprimi-lo junto dos outros dois valores requisitados. Porém, ao testar com o exemplo: 10 5 8 -100 13, ele imprime os valores 10 5 e 8, sendo que o correto seria -100 5 e 8. Vale ressaltar, não posso utilizar nenhuma função para reordenar os valores do vetor :(.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int quantidade, valores, menor, segundomenor, terceiromenor, i;
    scanf("%d", &quantidade);
    int vetor[10000];

    for (i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }

    menor = vetor[0];
    segundomenor = vetor[1];
    terceiromenor = vetor[2];
    for (i = 1; i < quantidade; i++)
    {
        if (vetor[i] < menor && segundomenor > menor && terceiromenor > segundomenor)
        {
            menor = vetor[i];
            segundomenor = vetor[i];
            terceiromenor = vetor[i];
        }
        
    }
    
    printf("%d %d\n", segundomenor, terceiromenor);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Começa por atribuir um valor muito alto às tuas variáveis "menor", "segundomenor" e "terceiromenor". Um número máximo cujo valor das variáveis nunca será maior que isso. Eu aqui defini esse número como 10000.

Depois testas cada valor do vetor para ver se é menor do que o "menor", se for atualizas os valores das três variáveis, se só for menor do que o "segundomenor" só atualizas os valores da "terceiramenor" e da "segundamenor". Por último, se só for menor que a "terceiramenor" só atualizas o valor dessa variável.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10000

int main() { 
  int quantidade, menor, segundomenor, terceiromenor, i;
  scanf("%d", &quantidade); int vetor[MAX];

  for (i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
  }
  
  menor = MAX;
  segundomenor = MAX;
  terceiromenor = MAX;

  for (i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
    if (vetor[i] < menor) {
      terceiromenor = segundomenor;
      segundomenor = menor;
      menor = vetor[i];
    } else if (vetor[i] < segundomenor) {
      terceiromenor = segundomenor;
      segundomenor = vetor[i];
    } else if (vetor[i] < terceiromenor) {
      terceiromenor = vetor[i];
    } 
  }

  printf("%d %d %d\n", menor, segundomenor, terceiromenor);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu dei um +1, mas o `MAX` define o numero maximo de itens, não o valor máximo de cada número (ou seja, um numero de 100000 ainda é valido).

Comment: Sim, tens razão, mas eu aqui utilizei o 10000 apenas como exemplo e por uma questão de simplicidade usei o mesmo MAX como tamanho do vetor e como número máximo de cada inteiro introduzido no vetor, mas podia ter definido outro número qualquer. O ideal seria o enunciado do exercício referir o MIN e MAX do input